# Play audio and video at a same time in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to play audio and video file at a same time? I want to play different audio file and video file at a same time and also want control for both, so is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not that I know of.  The movie view automatically stops all audio files and takes up the whole screen, so you are forced to listen to the audio for the video.

Answer (score 0):

If the audio is part of the video file, yes.

If it's an MP3 file or some other external type how are you planning on playing it? The phone [might allow this](http://www.ipodobserver.com/ipo/article/The_iPhone_Multitasking_Myth/) to happen depending on what you're up too.

You [might be in luck](http://www.intomobile.com/2009/05/15/apple-rumored-to-allow-limited-iphone-multi-tasking-with-iphone-os-30.html) soon though...

Another helpful link is [here](http://www.roughlydrafted.com/2008/03/13/iphone-20-sdk-the-no-multitasking-myth/).